# Install and Configure the Same GitHub Application Across Multiple Organizations within the same Company

Tags: github, github-app, github-organizations, atlantis

Can I install the same GitHub application, which is currently configured at https://github.my-company.com/organizations/first-organisation/settings/apps/app-github, in another organization within the same company, namely https://github.my-company.com/organizations/second-organisation?

I would like to know if it's feasible to install and replicate the same application's configuration across different organizations.

I want to keep the same application's ID, so I can use it in Atlantis, I do not want to create a different app in each organization.

PS: I carefully searched before posting, I did not find the exact right answer for my question.

I searched for an answer but it is not relevant for my case, I have already GitGub app installed in the first organization but I cannot use in the second organization.

Answer (score 0):

At the bottom of the app settings, the setting "**Where can this GitHub App be installed?**" should be set to "**Any account**"

Answer (score 0):

This one also confused me for a bit.

For a GitHub app to be installed on multiple organizations, it need to be "made public".

If you navigate to the GitHub app settings, there's a `Make it public` button.
After it's made public, when you go to the app's page and click "configure", or go back to the `app settings page` >> `Install App`, you'll be able to install it to your other organizations.

Comment: Hello, what are the risks of making an github app public?